# Does Jasper Webservice adapter changes the REST request body by filtering some characters?

Tags: elasticsearch, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I use the Webservice data adapter to query an elasticsearch nosql database. it seems that depending on the content of the initial query, I have sometimes a return 0 from elastic and sometimes not.

https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/web-service-data-source for Jasper Report Server 6.3

After investigation I have found the reason. The query works in jasperstudio inside the "Dataset And query dialog" but inside the report it fails i.e. one of the buckets return 0.

here is my body of my REST query (elasticsearch):
[image]

```js
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "storages": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "LN2_storage": {
            "query_string": {
              "query":"sampletype:Urine AND nbr.aliquots:>=3",
              "analyze_wildcard": true,
              "default_field": "*"
            }
          },
          "ALL_storage": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "NOT _exists_:parents.1",
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_field": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

The errors is located at  "query":"sampletype:Urine AND *nbr.aliquots:>=3*"

I think that the *'>='* is interpreted somehow. I don't know why. May be it is considered as a parameter ?

I don't know How to overcome this issue.
I tried with *nbr.aliquots:[3 TO 10]*

Any clue welcome !

Comment: What error do you get exactly? What results did you get with `nbr.aliquots:[3 TO 10]`?

Comment: Can you try running just the query with nbr.aliquots:[3 TO 10], no aggregation or anything else? Is nbr.aliqouts a nested field?

Comment: Instead of putting the complete query in JRXML, try to use Search Templates in Elasticsearch where you can store your query. From JRXML directly hit the Search Template to return the query result.